# Should order async be enabled on production?

Tags: magento2

I work for a project and "dev/grid/async_indexing" is enabled on production, should it be and for what reason ?

(It leads to an issue with "archive orders")

Ty

Comment: you want to enable in product mode if yes then you can change in direct database.

Comment: No, parameter is already enabled in production (with change in database). I want to know if I should disable it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check more info about "**Scheduled Grid Updates**"

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/order-grid-updates-schedule.html